# Is there anything like 'lies in' operator in js, as we have '$in' in mongoose/mongo

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to implement a function like this in js

```
            function(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfValues, property) {

/*here i want to return all the objects of 'arrayOfObjects' 
        which satisfies the following condition 
        (index is the iterative index of array 'arrayOfObjects')
               arrayOfObjects[index][property] is equivalent to any of
    the values that lies in arrayOfValues */

            };
```

example :

```
arrayOfObjects = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b:4 }, { a: 1, b :3 }];
arrayOfValues = [ 2, 3 ];

function(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfValues, 'b')
```

should `return [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 1, b :3 }]`

Answer (score 4):

```
arrayOfObjects.filter(function (elem) {
    return elem.hasOwnProperty(property)
        && -1 !== arrayOfValues.indexOf(elem[property]);
});
```

In case you need IE8 support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) functionality:

```
var a1 = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b:4 }, { a: 1, b :3 }];
var a2 = [2, 3];

var filtered = a1.filter(function(item) {
  return a2.indexOf(item.b) != -1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is too complex problem to have some build-in operator or function in JS.

You must use some cycle to walk through the elements.

```
function(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfValues, property) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < arrayOfValues; j++) {
            if (arrayOfObjects[i][property] === arrayOfValues[j]) {
                result.push(arrayOfObjects[i]);
                continue; //object already added, go to next one
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fun1(arrayOfObjects, arrayOfValues, property) {
    var result = new Array();
    for (var obj in arrayOfObjects){
        if (arrayOfObjects[obj].hasOwnProperty(property) && 
            arrayOfObjects[obj][property] == arrayOfValues[property]){
            result.push(arrayOfObjects[obj]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var arrayOfObjects = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b:4 }, { a: 1, b :3 }];
var arrayOfValues  = new Array();
arrayOfValues['a'] = 2;
arrayOfValues['b'] = 3;

console.log(fun1(arrayOfObjects , arrayOfValues , 'b'));
```

Your arrayOfValues should be an 'associative array' or key-value-pair object which use key to match the property. This might more suit your logic.